# Engine not firing on all cylinders on start

Tags: starting, fuel-system, vw, golf

Recently my 1993 Mk1 Golf Cabriolet (1.8lt, injected) has been having trouble starting. It takes a few attempts for the engine to catch and when it does it sounds like only a few cylinders are firing.

Usually I rev it a bit and alls good. Whilst driving and idling the engine feels fine - no missing and no change in power.

Feels like a fuel delivery issue, but I'm not sure.

Would anyone know what could be causing this? Feels like it's getting worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My money is on the cold start injector.  There is a fifth injector in the fuel system used only when starting the engine from cold.  This would be the very first thing I would check.

Comment: Yep - it was a hole in the fuel line leading to that injector. Thanks!